# Json parse() does not escape \" in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jackson

I have java object which is converted as JSON string using

```
    String paramMap = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(custPolicy.getParamMap()); 
    model.addAttribute("testTypeMap", paramMap );
```

In the .jsp page, on load I'm trying to parse the testTypeMap and get object back;

```
    var paramMap = JSON.parse('${testTypeMap}');
    showTestType('File content', 'LINUX', paramMap);
```

The object has double quotes (") in one of the fields, and it is escaped with backslash () when it is converted as JSON sting in java, that is why we see "\"" (from view source)

```
    var paramMap = JSON.parse('{"Filepath":"/home/status.txt","Search expression":"\""}');
```

But the above line says, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string".

I have seen few posts and they say it need two parses, one for javascript and one for JSON. I tried to replace \" with \\" ; but in javascript \" is always ", so I could not replace it;

Any pointer for what I miss here?

Comment: Should be `\\"` if the value of the property `Search expression` is just a single `"`

Comment: From java after converting as JSON string, I get \". But how do i change this to \\" i.e. double backslashes and quote in javascript?

Comment: What is the initial value of the `Search expression` - is it empty or a single double quote `"`?

Comment: it is just " (i.e only one double quote)

Comment: I do not write on java, but look here at example - http://www.technicalkeeda.com/java/convert-java-object-to-json-and-vice-versa-using-jackson

Comment: You will need two backslashes `\\ ` if you are directly entering it in the code, one for the JS parser, one for the JSON parser. However, a normal JavaScript string containing `\ ` only needs one.

Comment: @Cheery : the same way i do it. but as Mathew said in below answer, i do not know how to encode it. I see in php there is encode. I need to find a way, how to replace \" with \\", that solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was not knowing how to replace \" with \\" in javascript, as \" is always represented as " (just one quote without backslash).

So I did this replace in server side after converting to a JSON string using Jackson's ObjectMapper as below:

```
   String paramMap = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(custPolicy.getParamMap()); 
   // need to replace any \" with \\" in javascript side
   paramMap = paramMap.replace("\\\"", "\\\\\""); 
   model.addAttribute("testTypeMap", paramMap );
```

Now in client-side it shows as below:

```
   var paramMap = JSON.parse('{"Filepath":"/home/cavirin/status.txt","Search expression":"\\""}');
```

and this works fine as javascript parse is already taken care in server side.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not encoding the string in `${testTypeMap}` as a JavaScript literal.  I'm unsure how to do it specifically in your framework, but it's akin to HTML encoding a string, but for JavaScript instead.

However!

In your specific example you can avoid using `JSON.parse` because JSON is already in a format consumable by JavaScript.

```
var paramMap = ${testTypeMap};
showTestType('File content', 'LINUX', paramMap);
```

With the resulting source sent to browser looking like:

```
var paramMap = {"Filepath":"/home/status.txt","Search expression":"\""};
```

Comment: No, then this will be a complete string, I wont be getting as object, that is why I'm parsing it. If I do not have any quotes, everything works fine. I can parse and get java object back in client side. The problem is with quotes and I do not know how to encode for javascript.

Comment: Are you certain this will not work, from your given example, it looks like it should.

Comment: I'm sure. I need to have a object back, which I converted to JSON string in java side. The above code in your answer gives me string.